# Compilation error: object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found

Tags: vba, dll, reference, azure-pipelines

I want to import some data from an Oracle Database, but I don't want to leave the Password on the macro, as it is very easy to access. Then I found this code to hide myconnection string, which works pretty well, at least on my PC. I created a .dll of the next code so that the database data is not available for users.

```
using ADODB;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HiddenConnectionString
{ 
  [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual),
  Guid("2FCEF713-CD2E-4ACB-A9CE-E57E7F51E72E")]
  public interface IMyServer
{
    Connection GetConnection();
    void Shutdown();
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("57BBEC44-C6E6-4E14-989A-B6DB7CF6FBEB")]
public class MyServer : IMyServer
{
    private Connection cn;
  
    private string cnStr = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=YourPass;User ID=YourID;Data Source=IP:Port";
    public MyServer)(
    {

    }

    public Connection GetConnection()
    {
        cn = new Connection();
        cn.ConnectionString = cnStr;
        cn.Open();
        return cn;
    }

    public void Shutdown()
    {
        cn.Close();
    }
}
}
```

The next code is the one that I am trying to run:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

Dim myCn As MyServer
Set myCn = New MyServer

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset



'Consumos

rs.Open "select * from tablename, myCn.GetConnection


Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs


rs.Close
myCn.Shutdown

Set rs = Nothing
Set myCn = Nothing

End Sub
```

I've been trying to make it work on other computers but when I run the testing code on them i get this error:

### Compilation error: object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found

So it seems like the library hasn't been imported, but when I check on the reference list, my "hiddenconnectionString.dll" is activated, so I don't know what it going on.

Can someone give me some advice on how to make it work? Any help is welcome. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the dll is only installed on your machine.  Items in the reference list are not imported and/or stored in the VBA.  They need to be present on each host machine.

I'm not sure that hidden connection strings are a good idea.  [Security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is generally discouraged, as often it can be bypassed by anyone willing to invest enough time.

This design also uses a shared UID and PWD.  With each user sharing an account you lose the ability to audit who did what.

Where possible, I'd always recommend providing each user with their own account.

Comment: I make a copy of the .dll file and pass it to the folder where the VBA macro enables worksheet is saved, so... doesn't seem to be the problem, if that's what you meant...

I appriciate your advice, and I understand that there's no way to have the connectionString in a  100% secure way. But I'm afraid I can't make an account for each user as they need some priviledges to make the queries on my program. For the purpose of my program is enough if the "hacker" needs some effort to get the PASS and the UID, but I don't want it to be easily reachable.

Comment: I've seen issues like this before.  If you open the *references* dialog from a non-working machine does Excel state the reference is broken?

Comment: If you mean by broken that is "MISSING" no, it detects it, but then it fails to access the "myCn.GetConnection" function

Comment: I see.  Looks like your C# includes a reference to  ADO (something like *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library*).  Is that present on the failing machines?

Comment: Yes... "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" included!

Comment: Hhhmmm.  Can you add error handling to the dll?  A `TRY CATCH` block in `GetConnection()` might return a less ambiguous error message.